# Gradle release plugin with Jenkins not pushing release builds

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, gradle-release-plugin

I'm trying to use `gradle-release` plugin while using Jenkins for CI. Two commits are created on doing a release using:

```sh
gradle release -PuseAutomaticVersion=true
```

A pre-tag commit with say `version=0.0.4` and another with `version=0.0.5-SNAPSHOT`. The problem is that Jenkins only picks up the latest commit since they happen one after another. Due to this the release build is never deployed to the Nexus.

Notice the tick on only the top commit:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the green check mark is just a visual indicator that that commit did not break the build.

Uploading your artifact isn't something Jenkins handles per se, you need to configure the release plugin to invoke your Gradle publishing task as documented in the readme [here](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release#custom-release-steps).

So for example, using the recommended [Maven Publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), you Gradle build file may look like:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "maven-publish"
    id "net.researchgate.release" version "2.8.1"
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "https://your-company-nexus-repo.com/repositories"
        }
    }
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

tasks {
    afterReleaseBuild {
        dependsOn publish
    }
}
```

Comment: Just needed to add `dependsOn` part. Seems so obvious now, thanks a lot!